# Use WSL ubuntu in vscode and error in read file

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I want to use read the file in ubuntu. So, i run this code in vscode but there is an error. I don't know how to fix it.
and error message is

```
Unable to open 'lowlevellock.h': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/lowlevellock.h' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/lowlevellock.h').
```

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;
    struct dirent *file = NULL;
    char home[1024];
    if ((dir_ptr = opendir("HOME")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s directory can't read.\n", home);
        return -1;
    }
    while ((file = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this an error from gdb? It looks like you're trying to debug libc code which you don't have the source code for? Has your code crashed? Have you looked higher in the call stack to get back into your code?

Comment: There are various problems in your code which could be causing the crash. `home` is uninitialised. Your if condition for checking `opendir` is backwards and will only allow your program to continue if `opendir` fails.

Comment: You mean that something problem in opendir??

Comment: I compile this in VScode and error message show like that..

Comment: Thanks for help.. I think opendir is wrong. Thanks.... b@.@b